Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'
I am trying to run flutter build appbundle command and I receive this error.
Here is the stack:
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: /Users/armagangok/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/app_group_directory-2.0.0/android/src/main/java/me/wolszon/app_group_directory/AppGroupDirectoryPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: /Users/armagangok/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/android/src/main/java/com/example/flutternativeimage/FlutterNativeImagePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/armagangok/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/armagangok/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/cdad0845cf274cf31a832ff77b7149b2/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/armagangok/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/cdad0845cf274cf31a832ff77b7149b2/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Also my project level build gradle:
allprojects {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20'    
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

and app level build gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    namespace = "com.appsweat.pomodoro_app"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8' // Update this line
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.appsweat.pomodoro_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }

    buildTypes {
        // release {
        //     // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        //     // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        //     signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
        // }

         release {
           // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
           // Signing with the debug keys for now,
           // so flutter run --release works.
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

this is my JDK version:
openjdk version "17.0.13" 2024-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.13+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17.0.13+0, mixed mode, sharing)

have you already tried this? How to Clear Flutter’s Build Cache? Sometimes it is due to either corrupted build files or build cache.

Just a friendly reminder, sometimes, it is better to clean and rebuild
the project and test it first before building a prod app build.

Note: I did this when there was not direct issue with the source code that I've declared in my Flutter project codebase (.dart).
Or you may visit this forum for other way of resolving build issues: Update flutter dependencies in /.pub-cache

Yes, I tried it of course

I know it is confusing, but if I am not mistaken. I resolved that issue before by deleting the folder directory containing all the dependencies used for my Flutter app.
That package dependencies are stored at,
C:\Users<Username>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache
And I only perform this when there's no such project I've been working on aside from Flutter development (to not happen to you what happened to me).
Then, I rebuild my project.
It should be applied only when you are sure that the package you've been using in your source code is working and implemented properly.

Another thing, if you're having issues with dependencies, and if you're using Visual Studio Code.
Try to check the OUTPUT tab right next to PROBLEMS (or you can using shortcut commands: Ctrl+Shift+U) There are information about plugins' version you've been using, whether they're compatible with each other or not. It will update the information after by having save changes in the dependencies of pubspec.yaml file.
It is useful for me to understand the compatibility between my project and the plugins dependencies itself.
